# Reason for the compilation error : In function sk_X509_num undefined reference to `OpenSSL_sk_num`

Tags: openssl, x509

I have a P12 file which I am trying to parse programmatically. I am successful in parsing it.
When I use the code as standalone and use -ssl and -crypto on command line it works fine. But when I use the same code in my application I get Undefined reference error :  In function sk_X509_num undefined reference to `OpenSSL_sk_num` and In function sk_X509_value undefined reference to `OPENSSL_sk_value`

Below is the code snippet I am using :

```
{
  Bio *b = Bio_new(BIO_s_mem());
 if(b != nullptr)
 {
   for(int i=0; i< sk_X509_num(ca);i++)
     {
      if(!PEM_write_bio_X509(b, sk_X509_value(ca,i)))
       {
         //some log message.....      
       }
      else
      {
        //some code here
      }
   }
```

I have included in makefile the following flags : LDFLAGS+= -lssl -lcrypto
The OPENSSL Version is 1.1.1g

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could finally resolve my own question:

It seems the functions `sk_num`, `sk_value` have been replaced with `OpenSSL_sk_num`, `OPENSSL_sk_value`. There is an issue with linking, somehow there symbols have been missed in symbol file in the version `1.1.g`.

I tried the following:

i) Using `-lssl -lcrypto` on command line. This worked but when you use in the application and use the `makefile` with the options `-lssl -lcrypto` it fails with `error undefined reference`.

ii) Downgraded the `SSL` to the version `1.0.2` where in function `sk_num` is not replaced with `OPENSSL_sk_num` but it didn't work with the same failure.

iii) Success: So you need to define the functions for `sk_num`, `sk_value`, `sk_pop_free` in the application where you are using these functions, which I took from the SSL version `1.1.n`, which is the latest in 1.1 series. I hope it helps the people facing this issue. I tried upgrading `SSL` to version `1.1.n` but it didn't work for me.